# Encrypt data in PostgreSQL and decrypt the data in Python

Tags: python, postgresql, encryption

I have data in my database that I need to encrypt. I will then download the database to csv files. I have a python program that can decrypt the specific columns in a csv file. The problem is that I don't get my data out from the python program.

sql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION AESEncrypt (data TEXT,pass TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT AS $crypted$
declare
  crypted TEXT;
  key BYTEA;
  iv BYTEA;
BEGIN
  key := digest(convert_to(pass, 'utf-8'), 'sha256');
  iv := digest(convert_to(CONCAT(data , 'salt'), 'utf-8'), 'md5');
  crypted := encode(encrypt_iv(convert_to(data, 'utf-8'), key, iv, 'aes'), 'base64');
  RETURN crypted;
END;
$crypted$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

python program:

```
import csv
import time
import base64
from hashlib import sha256, md5

from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

password = 'Password'
inputFile = 'test.txt'
outputFile = 'out.txt'
delimiter = ';'
columns = [0]

backend = default_backend()
key = sha256(password.encode('utf-8')).digest()
iv = md5((password + 'salt').encode('utf-8')).digest()
cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv), backend=backend)

def encrypt(input):
    input = bytes(input, 'utf-8')
    #Padding
    length = 16 - (len(input) % 16)
    input += bytes([length])*length
    #Encrypt
    encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
    return base64.b64encode(encryptor.update(input) + encryptor.finalize()).decode("utf-8")

def decrypt(input):
    input = base64.b64decode(input)
    decryptor = cipher.decryptor()
    data = decryptor.update(input) + decryptor.finalize()
    data = data[:-data[-1]] #Remove padding
    print(data)
    return data.decode('utf-8')

def main():
    start_time = time.time()

    with open(inputFile, 'r') as csvfileIn:
        with open(outputFile, 'w', newline='') as csvfileOut:
            spamreader = csv.reader(csvfileIn, delimiter=delimiter)
            spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfileOut, delimiter=delimiter)
            firstRow = True
            for row in spamreader:
                if not firstRow:
                    for pos in columns:
                        row[pos] = decrypt(row[pos])
                firstRow = False
                spamwriter.writerow(row)

    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

main()
```

If I encrypt the file with the encrypt function written in the python program then I get the correct result if i would decrypt it.

If I would call the sql funcion as `AESEncrypt('data', 'Password')` then it returns the base64 string `Ojq6RKg7NgDx8YFdLzfVhQ==`
But after decryption I get the empty string as result and not the string `data`. If I look at the print statment before the utf-8 decode step in the decryption function it prints out the following on the console `b''`, so it looks like it could be something wrong with the padding. If I would print before I remove the padding I get `b'\x85\x90sz\x0cQS\x9bs\xeefvA\xc63-'`. If I will encrypt a long sentence then I will actually see parts of the text in the byte outputs above. 
Do anyone know what I have done wrong?

Comment: In your SQL code you're using the hashed data as IV, but in your Python code you're using the hashed password (neither is a good practice btw)

Comment: Sometimes everything you need is a second pair of eyes. I changed the IV hash to use the password, and now everything works fine. Do you have a better solution for the IV?

Comment: When encrypting create a random IV and prepend it to the ciphertext. When decrypting slice the first 16 bytes and use them as IV.